# How to handle hydration errors caused by browser extensions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As a NextJS newbie, I would like to ask how to deal with the hydration errors caused by browser extensions.

My app is working fine - without errors on the console - if I disable all browser extensions or use an incognito mode. However, using normal Chrome browser window the console is full with errors caused by extensions like LastPass, Grammarly and/or some others.

The error message is:

`Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

The problem is, that extensions add some extra tags, attributes to the HTML code so it is really does not match.

In real life I can not ask users to disable extensions or use incognito mode.

So how should I handle such errors?

I use React 18.2 and NextJS 13.2

Comment: Are you sure it's the extensions? I have them, and I'm using Next.js for a while but I never had this issue. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Yes. I have already solved the common related errors in my code. At the moment  enabling and disabling LastPass and Grammarly extensions make the difference.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue with LastPass.

Comment: This is a bug in React 18. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24430

Comment: I also used way too much time debugging this. I believe any extension that injects elements into the DOM can cause this issue notably: password managers, and typing assistant tools. I'm also using Incognito to avoid this.